# Как добавить исключение в .htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache

как сделать что бы не срабатывала переадрисациия при заходе на ссылку?
/awstats

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перед правилом, которое делает вам перенаправление добавьте соответствующее условие

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/awstats$
```